# upload sem refresh com FormData, jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Estou precisando dar um update em meu script e quero adaptar meus forms de upload para serem `upados` sem a necessidade de refresh. Não curto muito usar script de terceiros então eu pesquisei e me deparei com esta função do `jQuery` `FormData` .

Nao entendi muito o que li por isso vim aqui pedir um suporte...

Como enviar os arquivos para o servidor (PHP) usando Ajax e FormData?

Obrigado.

Comment: Há também uma maneira de fazer um upload ou post, sem refresh, através de um iframe que, no caso, é colocado como target. [Veja](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/post-data-to-an-iframe/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu utilizo o `jQuery`, sem plugin, para poder fazer o upload de arquivos.

Vou exemplificar de uma maneira bem simplificada:

**index.php**

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$(function()
{
    $('form').submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('image', $('#file').prop('files')[0]);

          $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: formData,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log(response)
            },
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false
          });
    });
});
</script>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $novo_nome)) {
     echo json_encode($_FILES);
}
```

É necessário enviar os dados via **post** pelo Ajax e, no formulário, configurá-lo como **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

Comment: Como escolher o local onde guardar o arquivo?

Comment: Quando você define um nome para o arquivo que irá salvar, você também define junto com ele a pasta. Exemplo: Quero salvar o upload como `foto.jpg` então faço `$novo_nome = "pasta/a/salvar/foto.jpg"`.

Comment: @Wallance Maxters, obrigado pela ajuda. Você sabe como fazer em jquery para verificar se imput file foi selecionado algum arquivo para iniciar o upload automaticamente?

Comment: Procurei muito por algo do gênero. Sua solução foi a melhor. Sem plugin, simples, prática e objetiva. Agradeço muito. =)