# Porcentagem em requisições ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar uma porcentagem em requisições Ajax. Por exemplo: Quando o form for submetido ele começa com 0% até 100% (quando concluído)

Meu ajax:

**index.php**

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$(function()
{
    $('form').submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('image', $('#file').prop('files')[0]);

          $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: formData,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log(response)
            },
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false
          });
    });
});
</script>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hey Hey, estou falando de porcentagem de progresso em requisições ajax, ele esta falando em progresso de carregamento de pagina. @renan

Comment: @Earendul ......

Comment: **Nota do moderador:** Se for duplicata, não é da pergunta que foi marcada. Reabrindo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que você pegou o mesmo código da resposta anterior sobre "[upload sem refresh](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43405/upload-sem-refresh-com-formdata-jquery/43442#43442)", onde eu também havia respondido.

Eu não adicionei nela nenhum evento referente à progress pois foi um exemplo bem simples mesmo.

Mas, se adicionarmos algumas linhas nesse código, é possível sim exibir o progresso de upload de um determinado arquivo. Isso é feito através do callback **xhr**

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$(function()
{
    $('form').submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('image', $('#file').prop('files')[0]);

          $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: formData,
            type: 'post',
            xhr: function() { 
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(myXhr.upload){ 
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log(response)
            },
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false
          });
    });
});

function progressHandlingFunction(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable){
        $('#progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
    }
}
</script>
<progress value='0' id="progress"></progress>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

É claro que isso se torna mais visível para arquivos grandes (já que em arquivos menores o `progress` vai chegar no máximo mais rapidamente)