# Requisição POST não é formatada AJAX Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Veja só:

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="paginax.php" method="post">
<input name="nome_arquivo" type="file"/>
<input type="hidden" value="valor_name1" name="name1"/>
<input type="hidden" value="valor_name" name="name2"/>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#enviar_form").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
                method:"POST",
                data: $("#form").serialize(),
                url: "paginax.php",
                contentType:"multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1922310697355",
                headers:{
"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
"Accept-Language":"pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
"Content-Length":"781659",
"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1922310697355",
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
                },
                success:function(){alert("foi!");},
                error: function(e){alert(e);}
                });

});
});
```

A questão é, configurei no ajax os cabeçalhos da requisição(headers), e no Content-type do cabeçalho coloquei: `multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1922310697355`.

Minha expectativa era que os dados a serem enviados fossem divididos pelo o que determinei no boundary(*---------------------------1922310697355*).

Porém, ao consultar a requisição que é feita, vejo ela sendo posta desta forma:

```
name1=valor_name1&name2=valor_name
```

Ou seja, além de não ser dividida como determinei no boundary, a imagem que eu selecionei no formulário(no input[type=file]) parece não ser enviada também.

Tenho 3 questões a abordar:

**1°**
porquê não é enviado o POST como eu determinei na divisão?

**2°**
porquê a imagem não é enviada, já que não enxergo ela nos dados enviados no POST(a não ser que ela seja disponível visualmente apenas pela var mágica $_FILES)..

**3°**
se eu determino no `headers:` do `$.jquery` o `Content-type:...`, eu preciso configurar o campo/atributo `Content:Type:` do `$.jquery` da minha requisição denovo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> porquê não é enviado o POST como eu determinei na divisão?

Provavelmente, porque o `jQuery` serializa o objeto que você passa no atributo `data` para um formato de dados de formulário (Query String).

Talvez a serialização do jQuery não está formatando os dados da maneira correta para eles serem legíveis para quem está lendo (o servidor).

Essa serialização é feita internamente através do método `$.param()` do `jQuery`. Então, quando você passa o objeto por parâmetro, assim:

```
{x: 1, z: 2}
```

... Ele os envia em formato de Query String, assim:

```
x=1&z=2
```

> porquê a imagem não é enviada, já que não enxergo ela nos dados enviados no POST(a não ser que ela seja disponível visualmente apenas pela var mágica $_FILES)

No jQuery, você só conseguirá enviar arquivos via post usando o objeto `formData` do javascript. Para isso, você deve remover essa serialização automática, trocando o valor do atributo `data` pelo objeto `formData`. Lembrando que a requisição deve ser POST :)

Exemplo:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('key', 'value');

formData.append('image', $('#image').prop('files')[0])

$.ajax({ processData: false, cache: false, contentType: false, data: formData, type: 'post'})
```

> se eu determino no headers: do $.jquery o Content-type:..., eu preciso
>   configurar o campo/atributo Content:Type: do $.jquery da minha
>   requisição denovo?

No caso, como você está enviando um arquivo, o `Content-Type`  deverá ser desativado, pois o `FormData` também já terá seus próprios headers quando a requisição for enviada. Por isso, desativamos ele como `{contentType: false}`.

Talvez, essa resposta que eu dei aqui no SOPT possa te ajudar:

[upload sem refresh com FormData, jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43405/upload-sem-refresh-com-formdata-jquery/43442#43442)

Comment: Wallace, perfeita resposta, só uma questão aqui que ficou, poderia me explicar o que está linha faz?
`formData.append('image', $('#image').prop('files')[0])`

Comment: Isso significa que você está pegando o arquivo do `input` do tipo `file`. No caso, como estamos falando, teoricamente, de um input de 1 arquivo, estamos pegando o índice `0`. Essa é a forma que se utiliza para poder enviar um arquivo para o upload via ajax :)

Comment: será, daria para afirmar que attr() e prop() pegam o valor de um atributo, mas o que attr() não faz é pegar o valor complexo, como de um arquivo(file)? fui pesquisar sobre isso e me espantei no tamanho da resposta, rsrs..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: Na verdade, creio que o prop se refere à propriedade específica do objeto. Por exemplo, você pode escrever um atributo com `attr`, porém, com `prop` você pega a propriedade do elemento como um objeto no DOM. Por exemplo, o Body tem o `style` que é definido como um atributo, porém o `innerHTML` pode ser pego com `prop`, que se trata da propriedade daquele elemento (do javascript) de acordo com seu tipo no DOM. Por exemplo, com o `prop` você pode pegar o `scrollHeight`, já com o `attr` não!

Comment: perfeito Wallace, um grande abraço e obrigado por ter colaborado!