# Enviar um video gravado via Javascript por input type="file"

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, webrtc

Estou fazendo um sistema de questionário para um cliente. Desse questionário algumas perguntas deverão ser respondidas por vídeo. Ao abrir a página da questão a câmera já começa a gravar o usuário. Estou conseguindo gravar o vídeo, salvar em um objeto JavaScript e executar ele no browser. Porém estou tendo dificuldades em jogar esse arquivo/objeto em um input type="file" para upá-lo pro servidor.

Estou com o prazo apertado... se alguém puder me dar uma luz eu agradeceria imensamente.

```js
var video = document.querySelector('video');

function captureCamera(callback) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }).then(function(camera) {
        callback(camera);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert('Erro ao acessar a camera/microfone.');
        console.error(error);
    });
}

function stopRecordingCallback() {
    video.src = video.srcObject = null;
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(recorder.getBlob());
    //video.play();
    recorder.camera.stop();
    //recorder.destroy();
    //recorder = null;
    sendForm();
}
            
var recorder; // globally accessible
function startRecord() {
    this.disabled = false;
    captureCamera(function(camera) {
        setSrcObject(camera, video);
        video.play();
        recorder = RecordRTC(camera, {
            type: 'video'
        });
        recorder.startRecording();
        // release camera on stopRecording
        recorder.camera = camera;
        document.getElementById('btn-stop-recording').disabled = false;
    });
};

document.getElementById('btn-stop-recording').onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    recorder.stopRecording(stopRecordingCallback);
};

startRecord();

function sendForm(){
    document.getElementById('tempoInput').value = tempo;
    document.questiontime.submit();
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <video width="380" height="280" style="background: #eee;"></video>
    <form name="questiontime" action="../controllers/sectionInterview.php" method="post">
      <input type="file" id="InputVideo" name="videofile" value="" style="display: none;">
    </form>
    <button type="button" id="btn-stop-recording">Continuar</button>

    <script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
    <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ali na função sendForm() tentei bolar uma maneira de setar o objeto no input antes de submeter o form, mas sem sucesso...

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errado!

Você não pode colocar alterar o valor do `input` via Javascript. A API simplesmente não permite você fazer isso. Ou seja, um arquivo no `input[type=file]`.

Mas, como eu já utilizei esse plugin, a solução que uso sempre é fazer o upload disso via `Ajax`.

Você precisa usar o `Blob` (retornado pelo método `getBlob()`) e enviá-lo.

Veja um pequeno exemplo com jQuery:

```
var form = new FormData();

form.data('video', recorder.getBlob());

$.ajax({
    url: 'url_do_upload',
    data: form,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false
})
```

Aqui também eu ensino fazer upload via jQuery:

- [upload sem refresh com FormData, jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43405/upload-sem-refresh-com-formdata-jquery/43442#43442)
- [Upload imagem no servidor AJAX serialize e PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102697/upload-imagem-no-servidor-ajax-serialize-e-php/102808#102808)

Comment: Perfeito Wallace! Consegui upar o objeto via Ajax conforme sua ajuda. Me quebrou um galho gigantesco... muito obrigado mesmo!!!

Comment: Wallace Maxters, percebi que via mobile esse código não está conseguindo UPAR o vídeo. Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: @AlissonPelizaro o problema é no upload ou no RecordRTC? Eu também estou usando essa biblioteca e ela ainda está em fase experimental.

Comment: O RecordRTC funciona perfeito, até consigo reproduzir o vídeo gravado no browser do mobile. O problema está somente no upload mesmo. Vou tentar debugar aqui no celular pra ver se aparece uma luz, rs.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver conforme ajuda do Wallace. 
Segue codigo final:

```js
  var form = new FormData();

  recorder.camera.stop(); //Objeto Recorder contendo o video gravado via WRTC

  form.append('video', recorder.getBlob()); //Passando o objeto Recorder como parâmetro POST

  $.ajax({
     url: "../controllers/sectionInterview.php",
     type: 'POST',
     data: form,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     cache: false
  });
```

E recebendo o arquivo simplesmente dessa forma em PHP:

```
if(isset($_FILES['video'])){

  $new_name = $idUser."-".date("Y.m.d-H.i.s") . ".webm";
  $new_name = '../uploads/'.$new_name;

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'], $new_name)) {
    echo "success";
  } else {
    echo "failure";
  }

}
```