# Como enviar Imagens via AJAX para o php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Boa tarde, gostaria de pedir a ajuda de vocês. 
Eu estou com um sistema onde eu preciso enviar uma Imagem de um `<input type="file>"` para uma pagina PHP via `$.ajax()` para nela, eu poder fazer upload desta imagem para uma basta, enquanto pego o caminho e armazeno ela no banco via `$_pdo`.
Eu fiz uma extensa pesquisa na internet e achei vários sites ensinando a fazer, porem eu não entendi, as únicas coisas que eu entendi era que eu devia usar um comando chamado `formData()` e passar alguns parâmetros no `$.ajax()`.
Porem eu não entedi:

- como usar o `formData()`
- quais parâmetros devo passar no `$.ajax()`
- se eu posso passar outros tipos de informações junto com a imagem
- Como eu consigo armazenar o valor de uma imagem em um `<elemento hidden>` e trazer esta informação para o `$.ajax()`

Alguém ae poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [upload sem refresh com FormData, jquery](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43405/upload-sem-refresh-com-formdata-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa criar um objeto `FormData` com `input` da imagem que você quer fazer upload:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', $('#inputFile"));
```

Depois, fazer a chamada ajax "POST" passando o `FormData` como parametro "data".

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://dominio/pagina.php',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Na sua página php, você pode usar o `$_FILES` para receber o arquivo.

Sim, você pode passar outros dados. o `FormData` é dicionário do tipo chave/valor, só adicionar outros elementos e valores fazendo `append`.

Tem um exemplo legal pra se você se basear aqui: https://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/

Comment: Antes de responder use a busca http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bajax%5D+upload

Comment: Verdade, já tinha a resposta, obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento